# multiple files from different directory, plot in one figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, argparse

Here is my script which can call a file from one directory. i can select file from command line using '-o'.

How can i call several files from several directory and draw in same figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This script only works for gromacs rms files and filename should be in 1.xvg, 2.xvg format')

parser.add_argument("-o","--input", help="output as PDF.")


args = parser.parse_args()
input = (args.input)
x, y = [],[]
title = "RMSD"
xlabel = "Time (ns)"
ylabel = "RMSD (nm)"

with open(input) as f:
        for line in f:
            cols = line.split()
            if cols[0][0] == "#":
                pass
            elif cols[0][0] == "@":
                pass
            else: 
                  try:
                      if len(cols) == 2:
                               x.append(float(cols[0]))
                               y.append(float(cols[1]))
                  except ValueError:
                      pass        

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.set_title(title)  
ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)  
ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel)
plt.savefig('data.png', dpi=500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply specify a list of files when calling the script with commas (no spaces in there):

```
python myscript.py -o file1,file2,file3
```

And then in your script you add:

```
inputs = (args.input).split(',')
```

And simply loop through all input files, e.g.

```
 for input in inputs:
     #Your code here
```

Note that you should create your axes before the loop such that you don't create a new axes in each iteration.